# Why do my objects "glide" when they collide

Tags: collision

I try to let some Tetris blocks fall on to each other. But for some unclear reasoning, they both move apart after the collision. I expect the object which falls, just simple "sit" on top of the other one. I've [made a video](https://youtu.be/ppPcjQk3_04) to show what happens.

I especially do not understand why they move at all, while the friction is set to the highest setting. What should I do to make the blocks fall on top of each other, and just stay there.

Both objects only have a rigid body set in the Physics tab, with the following parameters:

**Rigid Body**

- *Type*: Active, Dynamic
- *Mass*: 1

**Rigid Body Colisions**

- *Shape*: Mesh
- *Source*: Deform
- *Friction*: 1
- *Bounciness*: 0
- *Collision margin*: 0

Comment: The video link is not working.

Comment: Try setting the "Collision Margin" to .001. In addition if one of the objects is not supposed to move at all it should be set to "Passive".

Comment: Video issue is resolved